# passing a pointer as a local into a function

Tags: c, pointers

```
gcc 4.7.2 c89
```

Hello,

I have the following function:

```
void module_param_destroy(module_param_t *param)
{
    param = NULL;

    /* Stop the compiler from complaining */
    APR_UNUSED(param);
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
module_param_destroy(module->call_param);
```

Would the parameter `param` be set to NULL. As I am passing in a local copy, I don't think it is doing anything useful here.

Would it be better to do this:

```
void module_param_destroy(module_t *md)
{
    md->param = NULL;

    /* Stop the compiler from complaining */
    APR_UNUSED(md->param);
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
module_param_destroy(md);
```

The structures have globally allocated memory from malloc.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The first is only changing the local copy as you expect. `module_param_t**` is another option.

Comment: @justin: thanks for pointing this to me. Comment deleted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If param points to memory obtained from `malloc`, then setting it to `NULL` is not enough to properly cleanup.

There are two common ways to use `module_param_destroy`:

```
void module_param_destroy(module_param_t *param)
{
    free(param);
}
```

or

```
void module_param_destroy(module_param_t **param)
{
    free(*param);
    *param = NULL;
}
```

The main difference is that with the second variant, param gets set to a testable value to indicate it has been cleaned up. With the first variant, you have to remember yourself that the pointer passed to `module_param_destroy` is unusable after the function has returned.

You call them respectively as

```
module_param_destroy(module->call_param);
```

and

```
module_param_destroy(&module->call_param);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `module_param_destroy` looks good to me, but for completenes, this is working version of your first function:

```
void module_param_destroy(module_param_t **pparam)
{
    *pparam = NULL;
}
```

Edit: Yeah, as is explained in the other answer, that does not release any memory, so that is the last pointer to a `malloc`ed memory, you have to `free` it before setting it to `NULL`...

Answer (score 2):

The first version won't change the pointer because you're assigning to a *local* copy of the pointer, instead, use a pointer to the pointer to assign:

```
void module_param_destroy(module_param_t **param)
{
    *param = NULL;    
}
```

And call it like this:

```
module_param_destroy(&module->call_param);
```